# Chunked file uploads in Spray.io?

Tags: akka, spray, chunked, http-chunked

I have many clients that will upload arbitrarily large files (i.e., let's say up to 5GB). For performance reasons, this has to be done in a streaming way where the clients can split the file into a series of chunks before uploading them in parallel. Then, the server will take care of building the file from these chunks. I think this method is better known as **chunked file upload**.

However, Spray.io does not seem to offer any high-level building blocks for performing chunked file uploads. Am I missing something obvious here or do I really have to build this functionality from scratch? It's a bit weird if they don't since they already provide an easy to use mechanism to [stream response](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/advanced-topics/response-streaming/).

Comment: The reason is that spray relies on the third-party mimepull library to parse multipart messages. Unfortunately, the library doesn't support streaming access. https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/examples/spray-can/simple-http-server/src/main/scala/spray/examples/FileUploadHandler.scala contains an example which allows receiving uploads in a streaming fashion. However, as it still relies on mimepull for splitting the multipart message it may still load the complete data into memory. In akka-http this problem is fixed as streaming is an essential part of the model.